# run python code with opencv environment and dronekit

Tags: python, opencv, dronekit

I write a python 2.7 program that use opencv for image processing and control a drone with a kit.
if I run the the code with opencv environment,means that I have (cv) before the user name in python (ubuntu) , I get this error message

> No module named serial

if I don't run the opencv and just start the program I don't get this error message but I can't use image processing.

Comment: Could you edit your question to give some more info like OS and Python version at least?
Then, do you have the `serial` module installed? If not, install it from [there](https://github.com/pyserial/pyserial)

Comment: after installing this serial I got another error message: 'serial object has no attribute 'setBuadrate'.

Comment: It should probably be `setBaudrate` instead of `setBuadrate` :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after installing the serial fro here https://github.com/pyserial/pyserial
I get other message `serial object has no attribute 'setBuadrate'` 
after that need to upgrade the dronekit version and then it works.